# need help in extracting child node from XML file

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I need some help in extracting a child node from XML. my XML file is as following and I want to know if the child node "Stereotype "exists or note.by **NodeList nChilds = nNode.getChildNodes();** i do get child node but cant find child node in.
**XML File**

```
    < Activity BacklogActivityId="0" BodyFontSize="0" Documentation_plain="" Id="xJmijDqGAqB8AQnX" Name="Activity" PmAuthor="mameh" PmCreateDateTime="2017-05-22T10:47:43.779" PmLastModified="2017-05-22T10:49:53.126" Postcondition="" Precondition="" QualityScore="-1" ReadOnly="false" Reentrant="false" SingleExecution="false" UserIDLastNumericValue="0">
< Stereotypes>
**Stereotype Idref="e5bijDqGAqB8AQuV" Name="Context_Activity"/>**
< /Stereotypes>
< MasterView>
< Activity Idref="3xmijDqGAqB8AQmn" Name="Activity"/>
< /MasterView>
< /Activity>
```

**My Code**

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory 
    = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    System.out.println("Root element :" 
    + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
    NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Activity");
    System.out.println("----------------------------");
    for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
    Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
    NamedNodeMap att= nNode.getAttributes();
    if(att.getLength()==15)
    {
    **NodeList nChilds = nNode.getChildNodes();**
    System.out.println(nChilds.getLength());
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because it considers that text is a node child